# Strategy for creating a Radio Button Box:

Tags: html, css

Here is some code I modified from this [nifty site](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajhka/

I have all the elements styled with a checkbox images,..fonts, colors etc.

I just don't know how to do the layout.  I don't have a strategy.  But what I want is only slightly different from the fiddle.

I want the Title and Content Text aligned like they are but I went them placed to the right of the check boxes, where the title is at the same height as the check box.  This would make most sense and be the most readable.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: People expect radio buttons to be round, and checkboxes to be square. You shouldn't mess with established UI standards. Styling is one thing, changing shape completely is another.

Comment: I will update once I have the time...this is just a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ajhka/5/

I didn't change your CSS at all - just the HTML.

```
<form id="privacy">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="rdo">
        <label for="radio1"></label>
        <span class="privacy_title">Normal</span>
        <span class="privacy_content">When you add a bookmarks it is posted to the feed.  You have a public page which can be viewed by non-members.</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="rdo">
        <label for="radio2"></label>
        <span class="privacy_title">Private</span>
        <span class="privacy_content">The bookmarks you add are not posted to the feed.  You do not have a public page.</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="rdo">
        <label for="radio3"></label>
        <span class="privacy_title">Secret</span>
        <span class="privacy_content">Same as private and all of your data is encrypted using NSA approved algorithms.</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

To get this layout I swapped your `<p>` tags for `<span>`.  Then I wrapped each set of radio/title/text in a `<div>`.  You could tweak spacing a bit with CSS if you so chose.

Comment: o.k you put the span adjacent to the label.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I tidied that up a bit.  It's the most straightforward way I could think to do it - trade the block level tags for inline and everything stacks up; then wrap sets inside a block.

Comment: one last thing...the second span...is there a way to make it stop adjacent to the first span (just to the right of it )...so that it forms a "block" of sorts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking - isn't it already immediately next to the previous span?  Are you talking about having the description span all to the right of the title, including any lines that wrap below it?

Comment: just added in margin-left:26px;
float:left;

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle with a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajhka/2/

Looks like this is what you're looking for. The 1st row is with the header next to the checkbox and the description below it.

The other two are with all the text next to the checkbox.
If you want have all the others as example row 1. move the `<div style="clear: both"></div>` 1 row up.

If you want the description text to be aligned with the header text. use `margin-left` on your `<p>` element to align it or put it all in a `<table>`.

Comment: Yes but not exactly sure where you wanted the description text, that's why I did an example of two options

Comment: Do you want them to be as the 2nd and 3rd row? or do you want all to be as the 1st row